# why object is showing in hexadecimal in python after print?

Tags: python

Ex1.

```
class alpha:
    pass

a1=alpha()
print(a1)

# output:
<__main__.alpha object at 0x0000023CEFB9D040>
```

I wanted to know why the object value is coming in hexa decimal value?
is there anyway to convert to understandable format?

Comment: That's default representation. If you want to customize it, you can override `__str__()`

Comment: hex is just a nice way to write large numbers with few digits

Answer (score 1):

By default a class doesn't have any logic to "represent" itself in a readable-manner. When the print-function fails to find a way to translate the object into a string it will then return the memory-information of the object instead.

If you want a more readable output you have to define that behavior yourself.

Let's take these three classes as an example:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Test2(Test):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Test3(Test):
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

`Test` is the original class. `Test2` and `Test3` inherit the structure from `Test`.

We can define variables using the different classes and try to print them inside of a list, and then separately:

```
var1 = Test("Abraham")
var2 = Test2("Silvia")
var3 = Test3("Charles")

var_list = [var1, var2, var3]
print(var_list) # [<__main__.Test object at 0x02BBA118>, <__main__.Test2 object at 0x02BBA370>, Charles]

print(var1) # <__main__.Test object at 0x02BBA118>
print(var2) # Silvia
print(var3) # Charles
```

See that the only one that was represented correctly inside of the list was `var3`, but when we printed them out, both `var2` and `var3` returned their attribute `name`.

That is because when representing a variable inside of say a `list` or `dict` the interpreter tries to call the objects `self.__repr__` method to see how to represent them.

When trying to convert an object into a string however (as print tries to do) both `self.__str__` and `self.__repr__` is called, in that order. That is why both `var2` and `var3` can be printed out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing an object without a `__str__` function. As [Ganesh Saptue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2870572/ganesh-satpute) said this is the default output for an object.

Answer (score 0):

The `print` function ultimately needs a string to write to your screen. It does its best to convert various data types to good string representations, but in the case of your class there's really no way it would know what's a good string to use. So, the last resort is what you're seeing: Some details about the object, as well as it's *current location in memory* (shown as a hex address).

Answer (score 0):

There are various reasons:

1. Memory is often a very big number, into powers of 2. So, hex representation is used to compact very large integers.
2. Hex values are very related to binary values and to the numbers having power of

You can here in detail. [Why computer use hex to represent addresses](https://www.i-programmer.info/babbages-bag/478-hexadecimal.html?start=1)